# Python - Cálculo de juros básico dando erro

Tags: python, python-3.x

O código python abaixo deveria servir para fazer um cálculo básico de juros onde depois de mostrar a parcela com o juros, ele continua abrindo o box para fazer o cálculo novamente até o usuário inserir '-1' para parar.
Não consegui encontrar o erro. Estava rodando ele no Google Colab.

```
fin=0
prestacao = lambda fin, prazo, taxa: fin * ((1+taxa)**prazo*taxa)/(1+taxa**prazo)-1

def percentual(prazo):
  if prazo <=6:
    perc=0.07/12
  elif prazo <= 12:
    perc=0.1/12
  elif prazo <= 18:
    perc=0.12/12
  elif prazo <= 24:
    perc=0.15/12
  else:
    perc=0.18/12
  return perc 



while fin != -1:
  fin = float(input("Digite o financiamento desejado: "))
  prazo=int(input("Digite o prazo de pagamento: "))
  taxa= percentual(prazo)
  prest = prestacao(fin, prazo, taxa)
  print("A prestação do financiamento é:", prest)
  fin = float(input("Digite o financiamento desejado: "))
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: A sua variável "Fin" está fora do loop, ele entrará no loop caso o usuário digite um valor diferente de -1, entretanto ele não sairá já que não há um break ou a variável "Fin" não está lá dentro para ser alterada novamente.

Comment: Obrigado. Vi aqui os erros nos parênteses. O erro do -1 ainda não sei se vai ocorrer porque agora vi que o erro ocorre depois que dou o input da parte das parcelas. Acredito que o erro esteja dentro dos IFs. Além disso, coloquei o fin dentro do loop já.

Answer (score -3):

Imagino que o provável erro do seu programa seja a não interrupção do laço do *while* mesmo que o valor -1 seja inserido. Isso ocorre porque a variável que o seu código está monitorando é a *fin* - cujo valor é inicializado antes do *while* - e esta permanece com o valor inalterado durante toda a execução do código. A sugestão é que você altere a variável *divida* e renomeie-a para fin, ou, equivalentemente, inicialize *divida* como igual a 0 antes do laço e mude o monitoramento do *while* de *fin* para *divida*.

Há também alguns erros simples de sintaxe, como por exemplo fechar os parênteses  das linhas 16 e 23 - ambos nos comandos de *input*. Acho, e espero, que isso ajude.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado. Vi aqui os erros nos parênteses. O erro do -1 ainda não sei se vai ocorrer porque agora vi que o erro ocorre depois que dou o input da parte das parcelas. Acredito que o erro esteja dentro dos IFs.